# Count in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, qgis

I have layers named transformer, Service drop Wire, and consumer in QGIS and it is connected to my database Pgadmin 4 and I'm using Postgresql. These tables have one similar column called dtcode (Ex. 4344-D2), and the table transformer has a column called connected. What I want to do is, every time I want to connect a service drop wire and consumer to the transformer with the same dtcode, i want the column connected in transformer to count up, (Ex. the last data in the column connected is 14, and when I connect another service drop wire and consumer to the transformer, the column connected will become 15).

I created a function and a trigger under service dropwire and my query goes like this,

```
create function con()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
begin

update transformer t
set connected = (select count (dtcode) from consumer c where c.dtcode = t.dtcode);

return new;
end;
$BODY$
Language plpgsql;

create trigger con
after insert on sdw
for each row 
execute procedure con();
```

I want to know what's wrong with the code, specially in this part,

```
update transformer t
set connected = (select count (dtcode) from consumer c where c.dtcode = t.dtcode);
```

because everytime I use this code, the output is not right. It counts up, but only when I connect the second service drop wire and consumer, It wont count in the first service drop wire and consumer that I connect to the transformer. :(